# How to get the iTunes ORDER ID for an IAP?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I've got IAP and on purchase have access to a SKPaymentTransaction.

There's a transactionIdentifier field - which is a long string (about 2-3K).

A more practical and useful field would be the ORDER-ID field that's displayed on the customers iTunes confirmation email.

How would one get that field?

Comment: I don't think you can get what's not there. For what purpose do you want to use it?

Comment: When there's an order problem - I ask customer to email me their iTunes confirmation email. Then ideally I'd like to match the emp-id with what's stored on our server (SKPaymentTransaction info). If I can look at the email for the ORDER-ID and then compare that to the same value in the order confirmation - then I can activate them.

Comment: In above comment - by emp-id I meant ORDER-ID. Right now the transactionIdentifier is something that doesn't match with anything else.